# Vertical nav bar bug

Tags: html, css

im trying to write up a vertical nav bar, no proper styling just yet.
But i cant work out how to make the items appear along side properly.
http://javascript.nicklewers.co.uk/ this is just the basic function, but when clicking on 'Android' i would like the games and apps to pop out with Apps in line with Android

Comment: Can you post the relevant CSS/HTML?

Comment: Your markup is a mess, you currently have a `<ul>` in a `<ul>` directly. Make the nested lists nest correctly.

Comment: why dont you just put them in a DIV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search engines are your friend. i'd try that before asking questions here about simple things. you may get a lot of flack.

http://jsfiddle.net/HkDfQ/1/

```
<ul class="menusubnav">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Games</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Andriod</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Windows</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before writing huge scripts and a lot of HTML I suggest to have a look at [this](http://jqueryui.com/menu/) page. It's the standard Jquery UI Menu which has exactly the functionality you describe (i guess) and many easy styling options. In my oppinion you can save a lot of your time using this instead of writing something new. And mind the compatibility problems you'll have if you write everythin on you own.